# Bottom border on a link tag ignored by Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, outlook

I would like to set a `border-bottom` on my links in the email template I'm creating. Currently I'm testing the template by literally putting this **single line** in the template:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" style="color: #7f7f7f; border-bottom: solid 1px #00aac9; text-decoration: none;">Example.com</a>
```

There's a bottom border in Gmail. There's a bottom border in Apple Mail. There's a bottom border in Thunderbird.

There's no bottom border in Outlook 2013.

How do I hack the beast, so the border gets visible? Was looking for an answer on the Internet, no luck.

Comment: Outlook 2013 does not support `border-color` - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: You should use this website as a cheat sheet for css when creating email templates - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmm, I'm not really using the `border-color` property directly, am I? Or I am - as a parameter in the shortcut property. Yes.

Comment: Yes, you are as part of `border-bottom`

Comment: Fun fact: I'm using Litmus to test Outlook 2013. At first it did not show the borders below links. Now it does, after I refreshed the HTML. Not sure what is up, but let's leave the post for the future.

Comment: Maybe try using pseudo elements on your link tag.